# Include a variable as a part of a template variable?

Tags: angularjs

I have directive that I call like this:

```
<simperium-auth method="create"></simperium-auth>
```

I have added method to the scope so I can reference it like this:

```
<form ng-attr-name="{{method}}" ng-submit="auth(method)" novalidate>
```

This works great. However, I would like to add it as a part of another variable, something like this (though, this does not work):

```
{{[method].email.$error.serverMessage}}
```

Full directive below:

```
<div ng-controller="auth">
    <h3 ng-show="method == 'create'">Create account</h3>
    <h3 ng-show="method == 'login'">Login</h3>
    <form ng-attr-name="{{method}}" ng-submit="auth(method)" novalidate>
        <div>
            <input name="username" ng-model="username" type="email" required placeholder="Your e-mail">
            <div class="helper" ng-show="{{method}}.username.$error.required"><p>Provide an email-adress</p></div>
            <div class="helper error" ng-show="{{method}}.username.$error.email"><p>This is not a valid email</p></div>
            <div class="helper error" ng-show="{{method}}.username.$error.serverMessage"><p>{{this['method'].email.$error.serverMessage}}</p></div>

        </div>
        <div>
            <input name="password" ng-model="password" type="password" required placeholder="Select a password">
            <div class="helper" ng-show="{{method}}.password.$error.required"><p>Povide a password</p></div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="{{method}}">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you try `{{$scope[method].email.$error.serverMessage}}`?

Comment: doesn't work, I tested {{$scope[method]}} aswell.

Comment: Do the accesses in `ng-show` (e.g, `{{method}}.username.$error.email`) work? If yes, why aren't you using the same syntax?

Comment: @link, I concidered it, however, it will be very much extra code when I extend this concept. It would be much better if I could reference it  directly.

Comment: create is a form-object that is set using ng-attr-name="{{method}}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like this:

```
<p ng-bind="{{method}}.username.$error.serverMessage"></p>
```

ng-bind populates a tag.